# Diferencia generador o acceso directo al contenido de un Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Basicamente, quiero saber si hay diferencia real entre estos dos codigos:

```
cosa_que_quiero = [item[0] for item in diccionario]

cosa_que_quiero = diccionario[0]
```

He visto mucho código con la primera opción, y no entiendo porque hacerlo tan complejo.

Answer (score 0):

Son dos cosas muy distintas con un objetivo distinto:

El primer ejemplo:

```
cosa_que_quiero = [item[0] for item in diccionario]
```

- Itera sobre las claves del diccionario (`for item in diccionario`).
- De cada clave obtiene el primer item mediante indizado (`item[0]`).
- Todo en conjunto genera una lista con los primeros items de cada clave del diccionario, es lo que se conoce como [listas por compresión](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Por último una referencia a dicha lista se asigna a tu variable `cosa_que_quiero`.

Obviamente las claves deben ser objetos indizables (y obviamente "hashables") como una tupla o una cadena. En vez de llamar `item` a la variable debería ser `key` o `clave` para que resulte más legible.

```
diccionario = {(1, 2): 0, (3, 4): 0}
cosa_que_quiero = [key[0] for key in diccionario]
```

> ```
> >>> cosa_que_quiero
> [1, 3]
> ```

```
diccionario = {"foo": 0, "bar": 0}
cosa_que_quiero = [key[0] for key in diccionario]
```

> ```
> >>> cosa_que_quiero
> ['f', 'b']
> ```

El segundo caso es simplemente la obtención del valor asociado a la clave `0` (entero) del diccionario, si no existe obtendremos un `KeyError`.

```
diccionario = {0: "foo", 1: "bar"}
cosa_que_quiero = diccionario[0]
```

> ```
> >>> cosa_que_quiero
> 'foo'
> ```

De hecho ambos códigos son incompatibles con un mismo diccionario, en el segundo la clave tiene que ser un entero (`0`) y el primero intenta indizar sobre las claves y un entero no es indizable.